# How to go about serving a singleton object over the network in C#?

Tags: c#, singleton

I am creating a card game in C# for a school project. This card game is networked. The card game's game data is stored in a singleton object as gameData. gameData holds, the player names, which player the game is waiting on, player objects. Each player has 3 List objects. Where the cards are again custom objects. Originally I was going to create a ToByte() method for each card, player, and gameData object and serialize them to send over the network using TCPlistener. However running low on time I am looking for other ways.

These are the solutions I have heard of:

-SOAP (Have no clue how to implement this)

-Database (seems overkill for LAN, unless if a small database server can be made to run on the fly)

-Client Activated Object (but this create different singleton for each client)

What I would like to do is make that each client use their own gameData but using the get, set it would talk to a server that host this singleton object data. What do you recommend?

Comment: added the homework tag so answers can be more appropriately worded.  I answered by directing to "Enterprise Integration Patterns" http://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/.  A very good read, but probably too advanced.

Comment: What's the motivation for the singleton pattern here?

Comment: The motivation for the singleton is that its a crutch because our we where given 4 months to analyze reqs, and design with 4 months of implementation. Due to curriculum changes after 4 months into the project after the design was done the reqs were changed and our implementation was cut to 2months.

Comment: The WCF is my preffered way for me but I am going with remoting because it the least code away from what I have. also Mono is struggling with WCF.

Comment: @kthakore, sounds like a real project.  BDUF (big design up front) always short changes the product.

Comment: I know I am pressed for time so I had to do some design in my implementation phase. Not every project will give u the liberty of spending 80% of time on design ya know :(

Comment: So remoting was easier for me, but I know that the WCF would have been a better design. so I am accepting the WCF. Thx TJB and Afshari.

Comment: Actually, I was arguing that the 80% thing is a fantasy that always shortchanges the quality of the product developed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

WCF supports singleton services

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)] 
class MySingleton : ...
{...}
```

This way you have one single service instance that serves all of your clients.

WCF makes it easy to do network communication with very little network code.

Check out [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163590.aspx) for more details.

Combine the singleton instance with any WCF tutorial you find, and you should have a good starting point.

Good luck.

Comment: Glad to hear! WCF is the way to go for networked applications and inter-process communication.  If this did it for you, go ahead and mark it as the answer ;)

Comment: Ya I would have used this but I am trying out remoting. Thus I am leaving this open until I have decided between this.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is a school project, I think using .NET remoting is the fastest way to go :)

To make things simple and reduce nasty debugging and object management stuff, I would suggest handling everything on the server using a singleton object and return marshal by value objects to clients as data (again, since it's a school project). Give each client an ID to pass to the server object.

Comment: Do you have a tutorial for remoting objects somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

.net remoting is more or less built for the sort of thing you're asking, but not necessarily what you need.

Any remote access to a class is going to leave you with a "singleton" on the other end of the wire really isn't a singleton at all, but a proxy stub in local memory.

In your situation, I would add a service class (possible web service) that accepts in-bound requests and applies them to the singleton on the server side, then returns the required data. This will save you a world of debugging pain.

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid the singleton completely. Not only does is it a pain for remoting, but is often considered a bad design pattern anyway. There are lots of discussions here on SO as well as around the web about why singleton is bad. I think, especially in this situation, if singleton is going to give you a problem, avoid it.

[Edit] One of the main motivations for avoiding singleton is that singleton provides a shared, global state, which is the enemy of unit testing. Avoid it whenever possible.

Comment: +1, would give +2 (if it was possible) if you could explain some alternatives.  The problem is that "Singleton" gets chosen as a default solution too often.  What pattern would you use to solve the shared state problem?